# Weblogic admin console not starting

Tags: java, security, weblogic

I am seeing the following error starting my Weblogic admin server:

```
15, 2014 5:10:48 PM GMT+05:30> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.>
<Oct 15, 2014 5:10:52 PM GMT+05:30> <Error> <Security> <BEA-000000> <[Security:090735]The DBMS connection was not usable>
<Oct 15, 2014 5:10:52 PM GMT+05:30> <Critical> <Security> <BEA-090403> 
<Authentication for user  denied>
<Oct 15, 2014 5:10:52 PM GMT+05:30> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. 
Reason: weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user  denied
weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user  denied
at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 15, 2014 5:10:52 PM GMT+05:30> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED>
<Oct 15, 2014 5:10:52 PM GMT+05:30> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down>
<Oct 15, 2014 5:10:52 PM GMT+05:30> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN>
Stopping PointBase server...
PointBase server stopped.
x86_64 is not a supported Linux hardware platform for Autonomy.
```

I tried changing password in boot.properties but was not able to start portal admin console. I also tried by providing value from console by removing boot.properties files but still it is not helping . Do I need to provide `<node-manager-username>` and `<node-manager-password-encrypted>`  while starting admin console via startWeblogic.sh?

Comment: It sounds like a database error, not an issue with your username/password. If it can't connect to the DB, Weblogic will fail to start. See similar questions like: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2296545?start=0 You can attempt to hand edit the <domain>/config/config.xml and <domain>/config/jdbc/*.xml files to see if one of them is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You are using RDBMS authentication provider which does not use boot.properties for user authentication, it connects to the database and gets the user login properties from there to authenticate the user. Since WLS is not able to connect to the database its unable to authenticate and hence the server is not able to start..

The solution for this issue would be to swap the authentication providers, or make the RDBMS authenticator Control Flag to SUFFICIENT or OPTIONAL. Since your server is not starting you will have to make this change in the wls config file directly.

Comment: it is internally connects to database only, so it has password coming from db. Restored correct password and now it is working fine.